# filters the row data and summs it to see if it can give the result with reduce() combined with filter()

Tags: python, pandas

Figure out the sum of "Dwell Time" between yellow rows, and the result is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G6zF.png

Is there a better way

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need sum values per each 2 values of level column create groups by compare `level` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), add cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and replace rows with `2` by missing values in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html). Then pass it to [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and for last rows only add another `mask` with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'level':[2,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,5,3,1,2],
                    'dwell time':[1,1,1,1,2,1,2,0,2,3,4,1]})

m = df['level'].eq(2)
g = m.cumsum().mask(m)

df['dwell time 1 + 3'] = (df.groupby(g)['dwell time']
                            .transform('sum')
                            .mask(g.duplicated(keep='last')))

print (df)
    level  dwell time  dwell time 1 + 3
0       2           1               NaN
1       3           1               1.0
2       2           1               NaN
3       1           1               NaN
4       3           2               3.0
5       2           1               NaN
6       1           2               NaN
7       3           0               NaN
8       5           2               NaN
9       3           3               NaN
10      1           4              11.0
11      2           1               NaN
```